# Control.ControlCollection issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2010
Developing a Windows Forms application (C#)

I'm bamboozled by the following:

I create a class for organizing my data

```
namespace Project_Management_Wizard {
public class dataStorage {
    public System.Windows.Forms.Control wizard_tabs;

    }
}
```

I then put data in it

```
data.wizard_tabs = new Wizard_Tabs().Controls[0];
```

**Wizard_Tabs** is a Form that has one control on it - a **System.Windows.Forms.Tab.Control**.

So basically, now, data.wizard_tabs is a Tab.Control, which has several tabs with contents in them.

I then fetch those contents and put them on another form.

This helps me organize my form contents.

I do this by

```
   for(int I=0; I < data.wizard_tabs.Controls[Page].Controls.Count; I += 1) {
   this.Controls.Add(data.wizard_tabs.Controls[0].Controls[I]);
   }
```

Basically, this goes through a page's contents and adds every element that is in the page to the form I'm working in.

Basically, this should make the form I'm working be the tab's contents.

However, I ran into a bizzare problem.

Controls.Count as above returns "5", and I have exactly 5 elements on the tab, so that's correct.

I have two labels and three group-boxes.

However, when the loop runs, it adds elements 0, 2, 4; and skips 1, 3.
I checked in detail, Controls[1], Controls[3] have nothing in them.
It's basically skipping every 2nd element.

To demonstrate this, I added a bunch of labels down at the bottom.
Here is the wizard tabs thingy where I store my form contents:

![enter image description here][1]

And it turns out to be this after the code above is executed:

![enter image description here][2]

As you can clearly see, every 2nd element is just "skipped".

**Any tips on how I can make C# give me the contents from the tab, without skipping every 2nd element for some reason?**

I'm storing the TabControl's Contents data as a Control.ControlCollection.

I'm currently trying to figure out if it's a problem that occurs during saving the data, or generating the form, etc. I'll edit here if I figure this out.

---

Tests:

```
this.Controls.Add(data.wizard_tabs);
```

Successfully adds the complete tab control and everything within it to the form.

```
this.Controls.Add(data.wizard_tabs.Controls[0].Controls[0]);
```

Successfully adds element #0 from the tab to the form.

```
        this.Controls.Add(data.wizard_tabs.Controls[0].Controls[0]);
        this.Controls.Add(data.wizard_tabs.Controls[0].Controls[1]);
        this.Controls.Add(data.wizard_tabs.Controls[0].Controls[2]);
        this.Controls.Add(data.wizard_tabs.Controls[0].Controls[3]);
        this.Controls.Add(data.wizard_tabs.Controls[0].Controls[4]);
```

Seems to give me every 2nd element.

Somehow, after accessing a Tab's contents, every 2nd control is removed.

Even though controls gives me a count of 9, which are all the elements within the tab, trying to access them gives me an error out of index.

If there's 9 elements, you'd expect [0][3]...[8] to be there, but [5]..[8] aren't there.

---

```
    for(int I=data.wizard_tabs.Controls[Page].Controls.Count-1; I >= 0; I -= 1) {
        this.Controls.Add(data.wizard_tabs.Controls[0].Controls[I]);
        }
```

Seems to have fixed the issue, and it seems this.ControlsAdd() seems to mess with the  itself, somehow.

Thanks plenty!

But now I'm looking for a relatively simpler way of doing this.

I have the ControlCollection I want to display as data.wizard_tabs.Controls[0].Controls

So is there an explicit way to "this.Controls = data.wizard_tabs.Controls[0].Controls"?

---

```
            for(int I=0; I < 9; I += 1) {
            this.Controls.Add(data.wizard_tabs.Controls[0].Controls[0]);
            }
```

This also seems to do the job.

Apparently, Controls.Add(control) adds the control to the current element **AND REMOVES** the control from the source it's reading it from, collapsing the Collection where it took the element from.

I have no idea why it's completely undocumented that it does that, nor why would it need to do this.

Comment: You are modifying the collection while you are iterating it.  Yeah, doesn't work so well.  Iterate backwards from Count-1 to 0 to avoid the problem.  Do consider the wisdom of *moving* controls from one container to another, that's very rarely desirable.

Comment: When you add a control to a collection it gets removed from the collection it was in.

Comment: Unrelated but is there any reason you're still using Visual Studio 2010 Express instead of VS2013 Express?

Comment: I like VS2010 and I have no reason to go for VS2013.

Comment: Currently, I'm developing a few fun and useful for programming programs - a code organizer/project planner. If anyone has free time you can join me. This was part of that. skype: dimitar4yyy

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Controls.Add(control) adds the control to the current element AND REMOVES the control from the source it's reading it from, collapsing the Collection where it took the element from.

I have no idea why it's completely undocumented that it does that, nor why would it need to do this.

Code to solve the problem and demonstrate it clearly is:

```
    for(int I=0; I < 9; I += 1) {
    this.Controls.Add(data.wizard_tabs.Controls[0].Controls[0]);
    }
```

Comment: The control really can only belong to one parent, so if you add it to another collection, it has to be removed from the original, or the GUI won't work.